# firing $onChanges hook when collection is updated from the service in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

I am trying to make $onChanges hook work by using immutable way.

Chat Service

```
class ChatService {
  constructor() {
    this.collection = {
      1: [
        {
          chat: 'Hi',
        },
        {
          chat: 'Hello',
        },
        {
          chat: 'How are you?',
        },
      ],
    };
  }
  getCollection() {
    return this.collection;
  }
  getChatById(id) {
    return this.collection[id];
  }
  addChat(id, chat) {
    // this.collection[id].push(chat);
    this.collection[id] = this.collection[id].concat(chat);
  }
}
```

Chat Component

```
const Chat = {
  bindings: {},
  template: `<chat-list chats="$ctrl.chats" add-msg="$ctrl.addMsg(chat)"></chat-list>`,
// template: `<chat-list chats="$ctrl.chats[$ctrl.id]" add-msg="$ctrl.addMsg(chat)"></chat-list>`,
  controller: class Chat {
    constructor(ChatService) {
      this.ChatService = ChatService;
      this.id = 1;

      // if i get the all the chat collection by
      // this.chats = ChatService.getCollection()
      // and then use like above in the commented out template,
      // and it works and triggers $onChanges

      this.chats = ChatService.getChatById(this.id);
    }

    addMsg(msg) {
      this.ChatService.addChat(this.id, { chat: msg });
    }
  },
};
```

Chat List Component

```
const ChatList = {
  bindings: {
    chats: '<',
    addMsg: '&',
  },
  template: `
    <div>
    <li ng-repeat="chat in $ctrl.chats">{{chat.chat}}</li>
    <form ng-submit="$ctrl.addMsg({chat: chatmodel})">
      <input ng-model="chatmodel">
    </form>
    </div>
  
  `,
  controller: class ChatList {
    $onChanges(changes) {
      console.log(changes);
      if (changes.chats && !changes.chats.isFirstChange()) {
        // this.chats = changes.chats.currentValue;
      }
    }
  },
};
```

However, `$onChanges` hook doesn't fire. I know that in order to make the `$onChanges` fire, need to break the reference of binding `chats` in `chat-list` component from the `chat` component.

Also I could re-fetch the chats after adding on the `addMsg` method, it would work and trigger `$onChanges` but if the msg was from the another user and lets say if I was using `Pusher` service, it would only update the chats collection on the Chat Service not the `chat-list` component.

One way `$onChanges` seems to fire is when I get all the chat collection and then use `ctrl.id` to get particular chats when passing via the bindings like `<chat-list chats="$ctrl.chats[$ctrl.id]"` instead of `<chat-list chats="$ctrl.chats`. However, this will update chat list without doing anything on the `$onChanges`.

Ideally, I would like to update the chat list on the view by `<chat-list chats="$ctrl.chats` and then using the `currentValue` from the `$onChanges` hook and not use like `$watch` and `$doCheck`. I am not sure how to do it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks and in advance.

Here's very basic example of it on the [plunkr](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/okB5JGJaqm5NIA3c?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1&preview).

Answer (score 1):

Let's walk trough what your code is doing for a minute to ensure we understand what's going wrong:

The constructor in `ChatServices` creates a new object in memory (`Object A`), this object has  a property `1` which holds an array in memory (`Array 1`)

```
constructor() {
    this.collection = {
      1: [
        {
          chat: 'Hi',
        },
        {
          chat: 'Hello',
        },
        {
          chat: 'How are you?',
        },
      ],
    };
  }
```

In your component's constructor, you use the `ChatService` to retrieve `Array 1` from memory and store it in the `this.chats` property from your component

```
this.chats = ChatService.getChatById(this.id);
```

So currently, we have two variables pointing to the same array (`Array 1`) in memory: The `chats` property on your component and the `collection`'s `1` property in the `ChatService`.

However, when you add a message to the ChatService, you are using the following:

```
addChat(id, chat) {
    this.collection[id] = this.collection[id].concat(chat);
  }
```

What this is doing is: It updates `collection`'s `1` property to not point towards `Array 1`, but instead creates a new array by concatenating both the current `Array 1` and a new `message`, store it in memory (`Array 2`) and assign it to `collection[id]`.

> Note: This means the `Object A` object's `1` property also points to `Array 2`

Even tho the `collection`'s `1` property has been updated properly when it comes to immutability, the `chats` property on your component is still pointing towards `Array 1` in memory.

There's nothing indicating it should be pointing to `Array 2`.

Here's a simple example demonstrating what's happening:

```js
const obj = { 1: ['a'] };

function get() {
  return obj['1'];
}

function update() {
  obj['1'] = obj['1'].concat('b');
}

const result = get();
console.log('result before update', result );
console.log('obj before update', obj['1']);
update();
console.log('result after update', result );
console.log('obj after update', obj['1']);
```

As you can see in the above snippet, pointing `obj['1']` towards a new array doesn't change the array `result` points to.

This is also why the following is working correctly:

> One way $onChanges seems to fire is when I get all the chat collection
>   and then use ctrl.id to get particular chats when passing via the
>   bindings like `<chat-list chats="$ctrl.chats[$ctrl.id]"` instead of
>   `<chat-list chats="$ctrl.chats`.

In this case you are storing a reference to `Object A`. As mentioned above, the `1` property on the `ChatService`'s `collection` is updated correctly, so this will reflect in your component as it's also using that same `Object A`.

To resolve this without using the above way (which is, passing `Object A` to your component), you should ensure the component is aware of the changes made to `Object A` (as it can not know this when not having access to it).

A typical way these kind of things are done in Angular (I know this is AngularJS, but just pointing out how you can resolve this in a way Angular would do and works fine with Angular JS) is by using RXjs and subscribe to the chats changes in your component.

Comment: Thanks @Frederik for your explaination. Looks like I would have to use either passing reference directly on the component or use `RxJS` as you have mentioned. Here a example using `RxJs` 

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/JZOFEP62IALB97om?preview